# Is there any way to enable Overwatch League's overhead view?

Tags: overwatch

When spectating matches, is there a way to go and get OWL's overhead view or is that something that is specific to the OWL build of the game (like team colors and logos)?

If you don't know what I mean, sometimes you can see a picture in picture where the camera is high up looking down, and heroes are shown as circles with their current status (like stunned and such). I tried to find an example in a broadcast but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This view is only available in the tournament local server and not to the public. They should definitely make it available to everyone but currently, normal players like you and me do not have access to it

Best source I can give you is https://www.reddit.com/r/OverwatchLeague/comments/7rtqzq/how_do_the_announcers_show_the_overhead_view/dszkfy0/?context=0

Comment: That was my guess. We already know they are using a custom build for the spectating side of OWL, and some things are only in that build.

Comment: If enough people want it I believe it will be ported to public one day. With enough demand they usually make it happen

Comment: The replay feature, on PTR so far, will let you have hero highlight similar to the circles on OWL. You can then move the camera up to have a panoramic view of the map, with the circles representing each hero.